# How many sequences of n letters chosen from { A,B, ..., Z } are in non-increasing, or non-decreasing order

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

I am studying for a test and this is one of the practice questions. I really don't understand how to start this? It looks like a derangement question to me but I might be overthinking it

Comment: As each letter may be repeated up to $n$ times, consider the multiset $\{A,\dots , A, B,\dots , B, \dots Z, \dots , Z\}$, where each letter is appearing $n$ times.  This gives a set of $26n$ letters from which you wish to choose $n$.  For each choice of $n$ letters, they can be placed in (alphabetical) non-decreasing order in a unique way.  The same holds for nonincreasing order.

Comment: @Doc How do you guarantee uniqueness?

Comment: @nispio, I don't follow. Ah, yes I DO follow.  Let me think on it. Thanks.

Comment: @Doc Give each letter in your multiset a unique subscript. If the n =5 letters I choose from the multiset are A1,B1,C1,E1,Z1 is this really a unique set versus if I had chosen A2,B1,C1,E1,Z1?

Comment: @nispio, Yes. Got it.  After consuidering the difficulties of overcounting, I began to wonder if the problem was meant to be stated "without replacement".  But the fact that the verbiage is "nondecreasing" instead of "increasing" surely  suggests replacement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me see if I understand the question. So AAABNN counts (nondecreasing), and NNBAAA counts (nonincreasing), but NNAAAB and BANANA don't count. Have I got that right?

Looks like a simple in-and-out ("inclusion-exclusion") problem to me: Answer = #(nonincreasing sequences) + #(nondecreasing sequences) - #(constant sequences), since the constant sequences are the only ones that are both nonincreasing and nondecreasing. The number of constant sequences is exactly $26$ (assuming $n\gt0)$.

To specify a nondecreasing sequence of length $n$, since the order is determined, all you need to know is how many of each letter. I.e., $26$ nonnegative integers adding up to $n$, that's $\binom{n+25}{25}$ or something like that. So your final answer is$$2\binom{n+25}{25}-26$$.

**P.S.** The binomial coefficient $\displaystyle\binom{n+25}{25}$ comes from setting $k=26$ in $\displaystyle\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}$ which is the formula for the number of **ordered** $k$-tuples $(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_k)$ of **nonnegative integers** such that $x_1+x_2+\dots+x_k=n$. This is the so-called "stars-and-bars" theorem, which has probably been covered in class and you will need to know it for the exam. You can find this theorem (and a proof) on this [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29); it's Theorem Two. Watch out, I think they switched the letters around.

Comment: Can you say a little more about how you arrive at your formula for 26 non-negative integers adding up to n? Also, in choosing these integers, isn't the order important, since it is tied to a specific letter?  Does your formula account for that?

Comment: @nispio: I edited my answer to include some more explanation and a reference. Yes, the order is important: $x_1$ is the number of A's, $x_2$ the number of B's, etc. That binomial coefficient formula is for ordered sums, which are called **compositions** of a number. When the order of the summands doesn't matter, you have what are called **partitions** of numbers, and the formulas are very much different.

Comment: @bof, Well done! +1

Answer (score 0):

I would start by thinking about where in the sequence the transitions occur.  How many ways can you choose a unique "transition pattern" in your sequence? Given a transition pattern, how many possible starting letters are there?

Comment: The answer by @bof is much more straight-forward than this.