# Conditional combination

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

I have 3 objects A, B and C

and 3 baskets 1, 2 and 3

A can go to any of the basket

But B can only go to the same basket with A or in the baskets that has higher number than what A chose.

C can only go to the same basket with A or B or in the baskets with higher number than what A and B chose

For example, if A is in basket 1, B can go to any of the 1,2,3. If B chose basket 2 then C can either go to 2 or 3. If A is in basket 3, B and C then have no choice and will have to go to basket 3.

I was struggling how to formulate it in a general way to find the total number of combination, so that I can do it for any number of objects and baskets.

Comment: You are, I believe, just asking for non decreasing sequences made from $1,2,3$ or from $1, \cdots, n$ in the general case.

Comment: The accepted answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/546541/how-many-sequences-of-n-letters-chosen-from-a-b-z-are-in-non-increasin) explains how to do it with $n=26$, but of course the method generalizes.

Comment: Related: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/DyckPath.html

Comment: @lulu Could you reflect a bit more if possible. I am still trying to find the connection with that solution and my problem.

Comment: @AnindyaPrithvi Not sure how is it related, Is it possible to elaborate?

Comment: It is equivalent to making a $3\times3$ grid, label the vertical as basket 1,2,3 and horizontal as A,B,C....find the possible paths (hint: you'll have to sum multiple dyck paths), it is also equivalent to number of non decreasing functions as mentioned by lulu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general problem is:  "how many non-decreasing sequences of length $n$ can be formed from $\{1,\cdots, k\}$".

Call the answer $F(n,k)$

This is a [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem in disguise.  Indeed, every such sequence can be written (uniquely) as $$1^{a_1}2^{a_2}\cdots k^{a_k}$$

Where the $a_i$ are non-negative integers and $a_1+a_2+\cdots +a_k=n$.

(Note:  as to notation, the $a_i's$ just tell us how often each character $i$ appears.  Thus $1^32^2$ denotes the sequence $11122$, for example).

But Stars and Bars enables us to count the number of the good $k-$tuples $(a_1, \cdots, a_k)$, and we get the final answer $$F(n,k)=\binom {n+k-1}n$$

Check:  the stated problem has $n=3,k=3$ so we get $\binom 53=10$ which is easily confirmed (by just writing out all the cases, say).

Answer (score 0):

i think your reasoning is correct you could write something like this $$ 1 1 1 ,112,113,122,123,133,222,223,233,333$$

By the way in the condition of C there is a little thing that C can go A or B or ... which adds $121,131,232$ to our possible combinations but i think it is a typo :D

So $111$ means that A,B,C all go to basket $1$ similarly if we had $321$ A goes to basket 3, B goes to 2 etc.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand your solution. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: thanks my bad i edited now

Comment: Your solution is correct and matches mine but this is only useful for small problem. I am looking for a general formulation that will allow me to solve a much bigger problem. For example, 5 objects with 10 baskets.